# Is it possible to use resolves outside of states?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have site navigation that doesn't exist in any particular state. It's always available along the top of the page, regardless of which state the application is in.

I need to hide/show certain menu options depending on who the user is. I'm using windows authentication so a trip to the server is a necessity. The problem is since the nav bar doesn't belong to any particular state I don't know where to put the resolve.

Is there something like a global state which would be resolved first before any other states where I could put the resolve?

Something like:

```
    .state('$global', {
        url: '/',
        templateUrl: 'partials/navigation/navbar.html',
        controller: 'NavCtrl',
        resolve: {
            navData: ['$http', 'SettingsFactory', 'ViewMatrixService', function($http, SettingsFactory, ViewMatrixService) {
                return $http.get(SettingsFactory.APIUrl + 'api/nav', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
                    ViewMatrixService.GenerateHomeViewMatrix(response.data.CurrentUser);
                    return response.data;
                });
            }]
        }
    })
```

I considered using `$broadcast` but then I'd need to make sure every possible point of entry to the application gets the information the nav bar needs from the server and broadcasts it which contaminates all my other controllers with nav bar responsibilities.

Comment: That *genuinely* sounds like its own component included in your navigation HTML as opposed to anything to do with UI Router.

Comment: @Makoto I'm trying to use resolves, which are a feature of UI Router. In this case I'm trying to do a stateless resolve and I'm wondering if it's possible.

Comment: Yes, I'm familiar with UI Router and resolves.  However, what I'm describing here is a gut feeling.  You can get things with a resolve, but you still need some kind of state to persist whether or not the user has authenticated, and that's not something you really *want* to use UI Router for.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to find a way to use resolves outside of states, but I did find a solution.

I created an abstract parent state called `app`. I have a resolve in `app` that gets the user's profile. Then it can be injected into any child state controllers.

Since the nav bar is stateless, in the same resolve I pass the currentUser object to a service which is used across the app to store visibility and disabled flags for all controls.

It looks like this:

```
$stateProvider
        .state('app', {
            abstract: true,
            template: '<ui-view/>',
            resolve: {
                currentUser: ['$http', 'SettingsFactory', 'ViewMatrixService', function($http, SettingsFactory, ViewMatrixService) {
                    return $http.get(SettingsFactory.APIUrl + 'api/users/current', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
                            ViewMatrixService.GenerateHomeViewMatrix(response.data);
                            return response.data;
                        });
                    }
            ]}
        })
        .state('app.home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
            controller: 'HomepageCtrl',
            resolve: {
                homeData: ['$http', 'SettingsFactory', function($http, SettingsFactory) {
                    return $http.get(SettingsFactory.APIUrl + 'api/home', { withCredentials: true }).then(function (response) {
                        return response.data;
                    });
                }]
            }
        })
    .state('app.userProfiles', {
        url: '/admin/users',
        templateUrl: 'partials/admin/user-profiles.html',
        controller: 'UserProfilesCtrl'
    })...
```